# ng-repeat first and last page with limitTo filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angularjs 1.3 here:

I am using limit to in my table row as below example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in table.rows | dataLimitTo:limit:start">
  <td>{{r.id}}</td>
  <td>{{r.name}}</td>  
</tr>

 <div class="form-group" ng-if="table.rows.length>100">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" ng-click="prev()">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" ng-click="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

I have lot of data because of which I limit to 100 per page. Above prev and next button click help me navigate b/w pages.

Also above dataLimitTo is my custom filter (as limit to is not available in angular 1.3.4)

```
CTApp.filter('dataLimitTo', function () {
    return function (input, limit, begin) {
        return input.slice(begin, begin + limit);
    };
});
```

And in my contoller:

```
$scope.start = 0;
$scope.limit = 100;

$scope.next = function () {
    incrementLimit(true)
}
$scope.prev = function () {
    incrementLimit(false)
}

function incrementLimit(up) {
    if (up) {
        ($scope.start <= ($scope.table.rows.length - $scope.limit)) ? $scope.start += 100 : $scope.start = 0;
    } else {
        $scope.start > 100 ? $scope.start -= 100 : $scope.start = 0;
    }
}
```

Above code works fine and I am able to move b/w pages using prev and next button.

I also wanted to have 2 buttons for first and last page. If they press first page button they would come back and see the first page of rows, and if they click on last page button they would see the page of rows.

Is this doable with the code I have above? What changes do I need to make.

Sorry at this moment I am not looking for any other third party solutions.

Comment: @georgeawg sorry this was just an example so I must have written that in a hurry. As mentioned above I am not having issues with data binding and moving across pages. What I am not sure is how can I move to last and first page. Anyways I have updated my code and removed the ng-model part.

Comment: To move to the first page set start to zero, i.e. `$scope.start=0`. To move to the last page calculate the appropriate value for start. How hard is that? What problems are you having?

Comment: Start works fine. I was able to do the last page as:  $scope.start = Math.floor($scope.table.rows.length / $scope.limit) * 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move to the first page set start to zero, i.e. `$scope.start=0`

> I was able to do the last page as:
>
> ```
> $scope.start = Math.floor($scope.table.rows.length / $scope.limit) * 100;
> ```

It should be:

```
$scope.start = Math.floor($scope.table.rows.length / $scope.limit) * $scope.limit;
```

Alternately:

```
$scope.start = lastPageStart($scope.table.rows.length, $scope.limit)

function lastPageStart (len, limit) {
    return len - (len % limit);
}
```